# How do I use jquery's prop() to set the attribute of a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, attributes, prop

I want to use `prop()` to set the attribute of a checkbox to `checked`.

When I use `prop("checked",true)` I can visually see that the checkbox is checked, but if I look at the HTML there is no attribute value called `checked`.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="my_class" checked>
```

is what I would expect to see after using `prop("checked", true)`. 
However, I don't see any change in the HTML code. I want to later reference whether or not the attribute `checked` is set, but since there is not attribute called `checked` in the HTML, then I'm unable to reference it.

Comment: You can still reference it later in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `prop()` you are changing the property and not the attribute, so the changes can't be seen in a DOM inspector, but it is for all intents and purposes changed.

To later see if the element is checked, you'd do:

```
$('.my_class').is(':checked')
```

which would return true when checked or false when unchecked, regardless of what you might see in a DOM inspector.

Comment: The problem is that the checkboxes are inside a form, that when saved is set to ``display:none``. When I later go to view the form (by setting ``display:block``, none of the checkboxes are checked. Why is this?

Comment: @NancyCollier - That should work just fine -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c5NNs/) ?

Answer (score -3):

Is there a specific reason you wouldn't use attr() for this application?

If not, that's what you should be using instead of prop()

Comment: adeneo said it great in his comment: "When using prop() you are changing the property and not the attribute, so the changes can't be seen in a DOM inspector"

Comment: Yes, and the property is really what you want to change, that's why `prop()` would be the preferred method for this, it's just a little confusing in the beginning to not see things change in the DOM inspector.

Comment: I thought attr() was deprecated in version 1.9?

Comment: @NancyCollier - not for actual attributes, for properties maybe.